# sql calculate change and percent by year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an data set that simulates the rate of return for a trading account.  There is an entry for each day showing the balance and the open equity.  I want to calculate the yearly, or quarterly, or monthly change and percent gain or loss.  I have this working for daily data, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work for yearly data.
The code for daily data follows:

```
SELECT b.`Date`, b.Open_Equity, delta, 
       concat(round(delta_p*100,4),'%') as delta_p 
FROM  (SELECT *,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity) as delta,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity)/@pequity as delta_p,
          (@pequity:= Open_Equity)
       FROM tim_account_history p
          CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @pequity:= NULL
             FROM tim_account_history
             ORDER by `Date` LIMIT 1) as a
       ORDER BY `Date`) as b
ORDER by `Date` ASC
```

Grouping by YEAR(`Date`) doesn't seem to make the desired difference.  I have tried everything I can think of, but it still seems to return daily rate of change even if you group by month or year, etc.  I think I'm not using windowing correctly, but I can't seem to figure it out.  If anyone knows of a good book about this sort of query I'd appreciate that also.
Thanks.[sqlfiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c1073/2)

---

Using what Lolo contributed, I have added some code so the data comes from the last day of the year, instead of the first.  I also just need the Open_Equity, not the sum.

I'm still not certain I understand why this works, but it does give me what I was looking for.  Using another `select` statement as a `from` seems to be the key here;  I don't think I would have come up with this without Lolo's help.  Thank you.

```
SELECT b.`yyyy`, b.Open_Equity, 
    concat('$',round(delta, 2)) as delta,
    concat(round(delta_p*100,4),'%') as delta_p 
FROM   (SELECT *,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity) as delta,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity)/@pequity as delta_p,
          (@pequity:= Open_Equity)
        FROM (SELECT (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `Date`)) as `yyyy`, 
                (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`Open_Equity` AS CHAR) ORDER BY `Date` DESC), ',', 1 )) AS `Open_Equity`
            FROM tim_account_history GROUP BY `yyyy` ORDER BY `yyyy` DESC) p
            CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @pequity:= NULL) as a
       ORDER BY `yyyy` ) as b
ORDER by `yyyy` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.`Date`, b.Open_Equity, delta, 
       concat(round(delta_p*100,4),'%') as delta_p 
FROM  (SELECT *,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity) as delta,
          (Open_Equity - @pequity)/@pequity as delta_p,
          (@pequity:= Open_Equity)
       FROM (SELECT YEAR(`Date`) `Date`, SUM(Open_Equity) Open_Equity FROM tim_account_history GROUP BY YEAR(`Date`)) p
          CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @pequity:= NULL) as a
       ORDER BY `Date` ) as b
ORDER by `Date` ASC
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I see that you added a select group instead of the table in the from.  That is what I just couldn't think off.